# Stay on one page with different pages

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I don't know how to call this, but you can see the example on this page:
http://www.madeinebor.com/other/features.html

What I want is if I click to got to a new page, the menu stays on the page and it don't load again. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do a little research on AJAX and jQuery. AJAX allows you to refresh portions of a page without reloading the entire page from the server (asynchronous). jQuery is a library that is great for manipulating parts of a page using AJAX. For something like this, you would simply put event handlers on your navigation links and update your main content area when those links are clicked.

There are a lot of examples and documentation here: http://jquery.com

Answer (score 0):

Its called AJAX. In this only the partial page is loaded/affected, not the entire page. If you are on plain html and static web, then go for JQuery with HTML. If you had some dynamic pages then You should have to consider JSON, JQuery, AJAX with Server Side Languages like ASP.Net /PHP etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's called AJAX and is a method for loading data from server without refreshing the webpage.

It's a lot more convenient for the user, seeing cool effect and stuff without refreshing the page. But it's also a lot more complicated for the programmer, you'll have to setup the calls, process it on the server, and a lot more stuff. However, if one already understand the process well, he should be able to do it easily.

I suggest you to do a little reading on [Asynchronous Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_communication)  and [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to really understand it.